# iOS PreferenceBundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, jailbreak

i'm developing a iPhone tweak, with the Preferences i created a `PreferenceBundle` and in the bundle i need to call a SpringBoard method, but the results is always nothing. Is there a way i can call a `SBApplication` method?

i am using objc_getClass to get the class

```
SBApplication *app =[[objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:identifier];
```

when i use that to call the method the result is null.

Is it possible, or some hack i can do. i need to get the iconpath from the `SBApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to use the C SpringBoadServices functions. Go to your Xcode root folder and find the private framework `SpringBoardServices` of the iOS simulator platform. Set it as the current directory and run `nm` on the executable.

```
imac-van-ief2:SpringBoardServices.framework ief2$ pwd
/Applications/Xcode 3.2.6/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework
imac-van-ief2:SpringBoardServices.framework ief2$ nm -g SpringBoardServices | grep SBSCopyIcon
00009548 T _SBSCopyIconImagePNGDataForDisplayIdentifier
00009400 T _SBSCopyIconImagePathForDisplayIdentifier
```

Now you've found the icon path function name, you can call it. Declare it as `extern` and you'll be able to do so.

```
extern NSString *SBSCopyIconImagePathForDisplayIdentifier(NSString *);

myPath = SBSCopyIconImagePathForDisplayIdentifier(@"com.apple.String");
// Do anything you like
[myPath release];
```

Now, don't forget to link your final executable to the `SpringBoardServices` framework and to add `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` to your framework search path.