# Calling a SpringBoard method on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, preferences, jailbreak

I am developing a tweak and I've got a problem. I created a PreferenceBundle and in the bundle I need to call a SpringBoard method, but the results is always `null`. Is there a way I can call an SBApplication method?

```
SBApplication *app =[[objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:identifier];
```

Comment: I've edit your question, but I've made the assumption that this is on a jailbroken device (since SpringBoard is private). If that assumption is incorrect, please let us know.

Comment: I've done the same for the link to your other question that @Emil linked to as a duplicate since this will likely be closed soon.

Comment: yep it is a jailbroken device , can u help me with this  ?

Comment: please see my answer in previous duplicate of the same.... ok here also...

Comment: I see no point in reopening this; yes, it's really a dupe of [iOS PreferenceBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8757135) but is it worth reopening this just to close it again right afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

This link will give you some insight of how to use PreferenceBundle in iPhone...

http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/12/creating-a-preferencebundle-for-the-iphone/

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file

**EDIT :**

Can you try this code :

```
Class SBApplicationController = objc_getClass("SBApplicationController");
    id controller = [SBApplicationController sharedInstance];
    for (NSString *appId in [controller allBundleIdentifiers]) { 
        NSLog ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"bundle: %@", appId]);
        NSArray *apps = [controller applicationsWithBundleIdentifier:appId];
        if ([apps count] > 0) { 
            id app = [apps objectAtIndex:0]; 
            [self indexApp:app withName:[app displayName]];
        }
    }
```

or try below link...

http://pastebin.com/dQK5AXjD